# Getting current location in a WPF C# app using Geocode.Core

Tags: c#, wpf, bing-maps

I'm trying to get the lat/lng of my current location of my win7 PC, I'm using Bing maps. I've had some words with the guys at the SO C# chat room and they told me about [this](https://github.com/chadly/Geocoding.net) github project. Now I've downloaded the NuGet components: `Geocoding.Core` and `Geocoding.Microsoft`

In the example provided, an `IGeocoder` should be instantiated as follows:

`IGeocoder geocoder = new GoogleGeocoder() { ApiKey = "this-is-my-optional-google-api-key" };`

Now what I'm trying to do is using `MicrosoftGeocoder` instead. But the IDE doesn't seem to have this kind of constructor, the `new` keyword won't give me that option. Here's my code:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainMap.Mode = new AerialMode(true);
        MainMap.Focus();
        MainMap.Culture = "ar-sa";
        MainMap.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseButtonEventHandler(MapWithPushpins_MouseDoubleClick);
        IGeocoder geocoder = new MicrosoftGeocoder("KEY HERE");
    }
```

I should say that I haven't dealt with github very much so excuse my ignorance if I'm missing something.

Comment: There is a constructor : public GoogleGeocoder(string apiKey)
  So you can just use : IGeocoder geocoder = new GoogleGeocoder("this-is-my-optional-google-api-key")

Comment: @jdweng you mean I don't have to change the map object from Bing maps to Google maps?

Comment: The API will automatically call the Google URL with the github project.  You will not be using Bing.

Comment: @jdweng looks like I'm gonna have a bad time using Bing Maps, thank you for your time dear this is my second question with you around trying to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `MicrosoftGeocoder` type available in `Geocoding.Microsoft` but the constructor of `BingMapsGeocoder` accepts a key:

```
IGeocoder geocoder = new BingMapsGeocoder("KEY HERE");
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, now I have to figure out a way to get my current location

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, now I have to figure out a way to get my current location